# Chicken or egg type hibernate mapping problem

Tags: java, hibernate

I got a class with a one-to-one relation. Basically, in "class A" I have a one-to-one relation to "class B". This relation uses a primary key join column. Now my issue is as follows, if I try and create a instance of A, I cant save it because I haven't added a instance of B to it yet. But, I cant create a instance of B because I need the id of A first.

A easy solution would be to make the ID in B the automatically generated one, so I could then create a instance of B before creating a instance of A. However, I'm sure there is a better way of doing this? :)

I can see in the database that hibernate created a additional index on the id column of A, which im guessing is a foreign key constraint. And I can see the the documentation that the XML version of the one-to-one mapping have a attribute to specify if the relation is constrained or not, however, the @OneToOne annotation doesnt seem to have this option? :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have two relationships between `A` and `B` tables (you have: `A` has `a_id`, `b_id`; `B` has `b_id`, `a_id`). To model `one to one` you need only one relationship. Determine which table is 'main' and then drop column from 'secondary' table (should be: `A` has `a_id`, `b_id`; `B` has `b_id`). After that hibernate (and any other schema client) will be able to insert to `B` first, then to `A` with reference to `B` table.

For example for egg and chicken. There are multiple relations between eggs and chickens (one chicken can laid many eggs; one egg can produce one chicken). So for the `one to one` relationship egg-produces-chicken, it is reasonable to have `parent_egg_id` column in `chicken` table, so an egg can be created first and then a chicken with reference to that egg.

Hibernate mapping could look like the following:

In Chicken class:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_egg_id")
public Egg getParentEgg() {
    return parentEgg;
}
```

In Egg class:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "parentEgg")
public Chicken getChildChicken() {
    return childChicken;
}
```

**Update:**

The same thing as `constrained` in xml, `optional` property in `OneToOne` interface will do. It is defaulted to true, so the relationship is nullable by default.

```
    /** 
     * (Optional) Whether the association is optional. If set 
     * to false then a non-null relationship must always exist.
     */
    boolean optional() default true;
```

According to your comments rows to `A` are inserted first. I would consider having dependency from `B` to `A`, not from `A` to `B`. In this case to create item in `A` then in `B`, two `insert` statements are required (with relation from `A` to `B` - additional `update A` statement is required.).

Comment: Hi :) thanks a lot for your answer, but I don't have two relationship between A and B. A has a_id and B has b_id. As I mentioned in my post, I am actually able to insert B first, get the id and use that to create a A. I really just want to find out how to make the OneToOne property nullable i suppose, so I can create A before B :)

Comment: It is nullable by default. Refer to update section of the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, I got it solved. I think the issue was I was using a PrimaryKeyJoinColumn , which seems to create a foreign key contraint from A to B :) Thanks alot for the help :)